# Get event from dynamically added button in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I want to get the clicked event of a `Button` which is in my `UserControl` and I am adding that `UserControl` dynamically in my form. I want the event to be raised in the `Form` in which i am adding the `UserControl`. Please if anyone could suggest me proper way then it will be really very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own event to your custom user control.

Inside your customer user control, once you add the button, also attach your (internal) event handler that will then raise your own public event with some way to tell the event handler which button has been clicked (you'll most likely need your own delegate here).

Once that's done, your form can add its own event handler just like you add one to the standard controls.

Rereading your question, this might not be the exact structure (the button is fixed, but the user control is dynamically added?). In any way, it should be almost the same, it just differs where/when you add the event handler upon creation.

---

With one static button it's a lot easier to be done - assuming you're using Windows Forms:

In your custom user control:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked; // this could be named differently obviously

...

public void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) // this is the standard "on button click" event handler created using the form editor
{
    if (ButtonClicked != null)
        ButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In your form:

```
// create a new user control and add the event
MyControl ctl = new MyControl();
Controls.Add(ctl);
ctl.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(Form_OnUserControlButtonClicked); // name of the event handler in your form that's called once you click the button

...

private void Form_OnUserControlbuttonClicked(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever should happen once you click the button
}
```

Comment: hey Mario thnx for replyn u got what i exactly want.My button is fixed in my usercontrol.Only i am adding the usercontrol dynamically.please could you give me some example of what u explained.

Comment: Extended the answer. didn't test it, so might be some minor mistakes, but should hint you in the general direction.

Comment: hey mario i tried implementing what you suggested but i am getting ButtonClicked as null in this line -  if (ButtonClicked != null)
        ButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty); and hence may be because of this  the event on form is not getting called. Is there anything which i am missing....?

Comment: Check the fourth line in "In your form" and ensure you do something like that.

Comment: hey mario i have added that line and i am getting null exception for the same line

Comment: tell me one thing is this event public void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  is the event of the UserControl button which i want to get on form.

Comment: Essentially, yes. Once it's raised, it will pass this and raise the control's event, so in the end it will call the event handler in your form.

Comment: Hey mario i did exactly what you suggested but still the event on my form is not getting raised.. I am new to stackoverflow so i dont hav much reputation so i cant discuss this with u on chat and fear if our comments get exceed as discussion then it may go against this forum rules and i may get blocked.. so is there any other way round through which i can discuss this with u.. thnx for the help till now.

Comment: Ignore the chat message/question, it's still about the entry, so still fine. Did you try to answer of DigEmAll? His answer should provide you the complete code you should be able to paste/adapt easier.

Comment: yup mario i tried what you both suggested which is perfect but one thing which i came to know is since i am  adding my usercontrol on form dynamically on runtime which is my requirement i am getting ButtonClicked as null as i mentioned earlier so i had to abondon using usercontrol but what you both suggested works perfectly when i have usercontrol added in form in design time.Thnx a lot for your reply and solution even though it didn help me here coz of my dynamic requirement but surely it will help me in another projects :)

Comment: It should work in a dynamic environment too. You probably just messed the event handling somewhere. If you've got the time, give it another try and do it in a simple/standalone project first.

Comment: ok @Mario will give it a try because although we are not including it in our project now but i want to crack it somehow.. so will surely try it :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose the event in your user control, then subscribe it when you add the user control to the form. e.g.:

```
public partial MyUserControl:Control
{
   public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
   private void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (this.ButtonClicked != null)
         this.ButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

public partial MyForm:Form
{
   private void MethodWhereYouAddTheUserControl()
   {
       var myUC = new MyUserControl();
       myUC += myUC_ButtonClicked;
       // code where you add myUC to the form...
   }

   void myUC_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // called when the button is clicked
   }
}
```

Comment: hey is this private void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
click event of the button in usercontrol whose event i need to get raised in my winform ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using Winforms referring to your title.

What you can do it to forward your `Click` event.

So in the ctor of your UserControl

```
public class MyUserControl
{
    public event EventHandler MyClick;
    private void OnMyClick()
    {
        if (this.MyClick != null)
            this.MyClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.Click += (sender, e) => this.OnMyClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. when you are adding your `usercontrol` to your `form`, register the click event (if it is `public`)  `usercontrol.button.Click += new EventHandler(usercontrolButton_Click);`
2. register the button's `Click` event within your `usercontrol`